# How to pass variable to get_search_form()?

Tags: search

Is it possible to pass variable to `get_search_form()`?

I'm using it in two places: one in header and on the search page in the content. The latter must have additional class, e.g. `search--full`. I've tried to use `is_search()` but while it works well on other pages, on search page both forms have `search--full` class.

Comment: Under what conditions does the class need to be `search--full`. What variable do you want to use?

Comment: @JacobPeattie under no conditions actually, it depends on where the search form appears: if it’s in the `header` → no class, if it’s in the `main` → add class.

Comment: Are you hard-coding the form into these places, or trying to respond to where a user might have placed it?

Comment: I am hard-coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass custom args to get_search_form() when calling it:

```
get_search_form(array('test' => 'hello'))
```

Then in **searchform.php** it all will be available under $args variable

```
echo($args['test']); // Will print "hello"
```

Just be aware in your searchform.php file that this file is called everywhere get_search_form() is used so you most likely want to check that such key exists first

```
if(array_key_exists('test', $args)){
   echo($args['test']); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a more proper way to solve this as pointed in many cases would be :

```
//include search form in header
include(locate_template('template-header-search.php'));
//include search form in body
include(locate_template('template-body-search.php'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it require to create two templates?

Comment: `get_template_part()` would be the preferred way of including a template.

Comment: @Runnick Yes it would require two templates but you can tweak that add a global variable to differentiate between which one